# C++ Overload operator == in myStack.h

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.  I can not change the function definitions, I must use them as is.  I am supposed to overload the operator==, which is at the very bottom of the code.

I keep getting this error:

> Error  C2662           'void stackType::copyStack(const
>   stackType &)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const
>   stackType' to 'stackType &'

Here is my code:

```
//Header file: myStack.h

#ifndef H_StackType
#define H_StackType

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include "stackADT.h"

using namespace std;

//*************************************************************
// This class specifies the basic operation on a stack as an 
// array.
//*************************************************************

template <class Type>
class stackType: public stackADT<Type>
{
public:
    const stackType<Type>& operator=(const stackType<Type>&); 
      //Overload the assignment operator.

    void initializeStack();
      //Function to initialize the stack to an empty state.
      //Postcondition: stackTop = 0;

    bool isEmptyStack() const;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is empty.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty,
      //    otherwise returns false.

    bool isFullStack() const;
      //Function to determine whether the stack is full.
      //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is full,
      //    otherwise returns false.

    void push(const Type& newItem);
      //Function to add newItem to the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem is
      //    added to the top of the stack.

    Type top() const;
      //Function to return the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the program 
      //    terminates; otherwise, the top element of the stack
      //    is returned.

    void pop();
      //Function to remove the top element of the stack.
      //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
      //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top element is
      //    removed from the stack.

    bool operator==(const stackType<Type>& otherStack) const;

    stackType(int stackSize = 100); 
      //Constructor
      //Create an array of the size stackSize to hold 
      //the stack elements. The default stack size is 100.
      //Postcondition: The variable list contains the base address 
      //   of the array, stackTop = 0, and maxStackSize = stackSize

    stackType(const stackType<Type>& otherStack); 
      //Copy constructor

    ~stackType(); 
      //Destructor
      //Remove all the elements from the stack.
      //Postcondition: The array (list) holding the stack 
      //    elements is deleted.

private:
    int maxStackSize; //variable to store the maximum stack size
    int stackTop;     //variable to point to the top of the stack
    Type *list; //pointer to the array that holds the stack elements

    void copyStack(const stackType<Type>& otherStack); 
      //Function to make a copy of otherStack.
      //Postcondition: A copy of otherStack is created and assigned
      //    to this stack.
};

template <class Type>
void stackType<Type>::initializeStack()
{
    stackTop = 0;
}//end initializeStack

template <class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::isEmptyStack() const
{
    return(stackTop == 0);
}//end isEmptyStack

template <class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::isFullStack() const
{
    return(stackTop == maxStackSize);
} //end isFullStack

template <class Type>
void stackType<Type>::push(const Type& newItem)
{
    if (!isFullStack())
    {
        list[stackTop] = newItem;   //add newItem to the 
                                    //top of the stack
        stackTop++; //increment stackTop
    }
    else
        cout << "Cannot add to a full stack." << endl;
}//end push

template <class Type>
Type stackType<Type>::top() const
{
    assert(stackTop != 0);          //if stack is empty, 
                                    //terminate the program
    return list[stackTop - 1];      //return the element of the
                                    //stack indicated by 
                                    //stackTop - 1
}//end top

template <class Type>
void stackType<Type>::pop()
{
    if (!isEmptyStack())
        stackTop--;                 //decrement stackTop 
    else
        cout << "Cannot remove from an empty stack." << endl;
}//end pop

template <class Type>
stackType<Type>::stackType(int stackSize)
{
    if (stackSize <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Size of the array to hold the stack must "
            << "be positive." << endl;
        cout << "Creating an array of size 100." << endl;

        maxStackSize = 100;
    }
    else
        maxStackSize = stackSize;   //set the stack size to 
                                    //the value specified by
                                    //the parameter stackSize

    stackTop = 0;                   //set stackTop to 0
    list = new Type[maxStackSize];  //create the array to
                                    //hold the stack elements
}//end constructor

template <class Type>
stackType<Type>::~stackType() //destructor
{
    delete[] list; //deallocate the memory occupied 
                   //by the array
}//end destructor

template <class Type>
void stackType<Type>::copyStack(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    delete[] list;
    maxStackSize = otherStack.maxStackSize;
    stackTop = otherStack.stackTop;

    list = new Type[maxStackSize];

    //copy otherStack into this stack
    for (int j = 0; j < stackTop; j++)
        list[j] = otherStack.list[j];
} //end copyStack


template <class Type>
stackType<Type>::stackType(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    list = NULL;

    copyStack(otherStack);
}//end copy constructor

template <class Type>
const stackType<Type>& stackType<Type>::operator= (const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    if (this != &otherStack) //avoid self-copy
        copyStack(otherStack);

    return *this;
} //end operator= 

template <class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::operator== (const stackType<Type>& otherStack) const
{
    stackType<Type> stackA, stackB;
    bool result = false;
    copyStack(stackA);
    otherStack.copyStack(stackB);

    while (!stackA.isEmptyStack() && !stackB.isEmptyStack())
    {
        if (stackA.top() == stackB.top())
        {
            stackA.pop();
            stackB.pop();
            if (stackA.isEmptyStack() && stackB.isEmptyStack())
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

    }

    return result;

}

#endif
```

Comment: Did you read the docs of `copystack`? "A copy of otherStack is created and assigned to this stack." Does that correspond with the way you call it?

Comment: You should break after result = false. No need to go on checking and in fact you can get a false positive

Answer (score 2):

```
copyStack(stackA);
```

Your `operator==` const method calls the `copyStack()` method, which is a non-const method.

A `const` method can only call other `const` methods. A brief examination of your code seems to suggest that you meant to do

```
stackA.copyStack(*this);
```

instead. Your `operator==` obviously intends to copy both objects being compared into temporary `Stacktype` objects, first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confused about what to call `copyStack` on.
I believe these two lines:

```
copyStack(stackA);                                                           
otherStack.copyStack(stackB);
```

Should be

```
stackA.copyStack(*this);                                                           
stackB.copyStack(otherStack);
```

Otherwise, you are copying the empty `stackA` into yourself, and then `stackB` into `otherStack`.  Since the receiver of `copyStack` is non-const (ie `copyStack` is a non-const member function), this fails. This seems like an odd way to implement `operator==` since you could compare the existing elements rather than copy and pop repeatedly though.